# input-field not refresh after receiving value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The entire process of collecting data from the first input-field and shipping to second input-field2 is working perfectly but so that the value actually goes to the second input-field i must delete some letter from first input-field and re-enter some number so that the value actually goes to second-input.

Gif of doubt.[image]

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(function () {
        var $cepAddressRouteTransporterGoogleMaps = $('#postal_code');
        var $cepAddressRouteTransporter = $('#cepAddressRouteTransporter');

        function onChange() {
          $cepAddressRouteTransporter.val($cepAddressRouteTransporterGoogleMaps.val());
        };

        $('#postal_code')
          .change(onChange)
          .keyup(onChange);
      });
    });
```

First input represents this field `postal_code` & Second input represents this field `cepAddressRouteTransporter`.

```
<form action="transporter/route" method="post" role="form">
  <table id="address">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Zip code</td>
      <td class="wideField">
        <input class="field" id="postal_code" name="postal_code">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">directions</i>
    <input placeholder="Ex: 18214-780" id="cepAddressRouteTransporter" name="cepAddressRouteTransporter" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="cepAddressRouteTransporter">CEP:</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Problem is not clear

Comment: @charlietfl i explained at the beginning of the question, the value actually goes to the second input-field i need to re-enter some numbers

Comment: well the second part of that comment is the part that is not clear and is confusing. Provide sample of input values and expected results

Comment: In image problem seems to be related to an auto complete that isn't shown in any of the code in question

Comment: @charlietfl the input `postal_code` result after selecting a street in the google maps auto complete; if you want i can add script of google maps to complement the issue. if i add the my `$(function() { });`  inside of google maps script responsible for researching this data and returning in a input-field `postal_code` can it be made more effective by being together with script search for zip codes?

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve]. It sounds like you are only updating one if the inputs in the auto complete code and not the other but not entirley clear what objective or problem really is here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to call your function `onChange` when the DOM is ready

```
onChange();
```

when you update the value, trigger the DOM event.

```
$('#postal_code').trigger('change');
```

```js
$(function() {
    var $cepAddressRouteTransporterGoogleMaps = $('#postal_code');
    var $cepAddressRouteTransporter = $('#cepAddressRouteTransporter');

    function onChange() {
        $cepAddressRouteTransporter.val($cepAddressRouteTransporterGoogleMaps.val());
    };

    $('#postal_code').change(onChange).keyup(onChange);
        
    // fire as soon as DOM is ready
    onChange();
    
    var t = window.setInterval(function(){
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
        $('#postal_code').val(n);
        
        // when you update the value, trigger the DOM event
        $('#postal_code').trigger('change');
    },1000);
        
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="transporter/route" method="post" role="form">
  <table id="address">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Zip code</td>
      <td class="wideField">
        <input class="field" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" value="90210">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">directions</i>
    <input placeholder="Ex: 18214-780" id="cepAddressRouteTransporter" name="cepAddressRouteTransporter" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="cepAddressRouteTransporter">CEP:</label>
  </div>

</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it returns the value but does not update the field `cepAddressRouteTransporter` a user action is required so that this value is sent to `cepAddressRouteTransporter`

Comment: i updated answer to, when you update the value, trigger the DOM event

Answer (score 1):

@code_monk Thanks for your help, i've reshaped your recommendation and add a few new things.

```
    $(function () {
      var $cepAddressRouteTransporterGoogleMaps = $('#postal_code');
      var $cepAddressRouteTransporter = $('#cepAddressRouteTransporter');

      function onChange() {
        $cepAddressRouteTransporter.val($cepAddressRouteTransporterGoogleMaps.val());
      };

      $cepAddressRouteTransporterGoogleMaps.change(onChange).keyup(onChange);
      $cepAddressRouteTransporter.change(onChange).keyup(onChange);

      onChange();

      var refresh = window.setInterval(function () {
        $cepAddressRouteTransporter.val($cepAddressRouteTransporterGoogleMaps.val());
      }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: cool! if you're looking for code review, post your code here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/